# Unable to launch .jar file

Tags: java, jar

I created a project that contains a `JFrame` and other JObjects. It also contains picture and other classes that have their own `JFrame` and JObjects, but I can't seem to get the .jar launching correctly.

I'm using DrJava and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I clicked "create .jar from project", I put the main class in the text field, and it should create a .jar file. Except, when I look at the file, it's not a .jar but just a file.

If I change it to .jar it doesn't run. If I open it with WinRAR my classes and pictures and everything are in there. If I try to launch it in DrJava it immediately says "Execution of jar file terminated (exit value =1)". 
As it's creating the .jar file, I get an error, it has all my classes under why and it says "Duplicate: (Insert one of my classes)$", but it says that DrJava was probably able to recover. After a second or two it says ".jar created successfully". If I try to launch it in CMD it doesn't open and I get a whole bunch of line errors, but if I compile it in DrJava it runs perfectly.

Why is this?

Comment: What errors are you getting in the command line?

Comment: @shmosel Hmm, yesterday I was getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: but now im getting could not find or load main class (Directly of my main class).myMainClass

Comment: Try making a jar through `jar -cfe <jar name> <class with main method> <class files>`, for example `jar -cfe Example.jar Example Example.class`

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't add a `Main Class` to run the program. I think you can add the main class using project properties in `Dr.Java` As in this [Dr. Java](http://www.drjava.org/docs/quickstart/ch05s10.html)

Comment: " I put the main class in the text field,  and it should create a .jar file". I did put a main class.

Comment: What do you mean by `put the main class in the text field`?

Answer (score 0):

A file opened in DrJava probably has to be saved as a .java file. Its one of the many shortcomings of DrJava